# Xcode: weird build failure when duplicating a build configuration

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, buildconfiguration

I duplicated an existing build configuration in my Xcode project called `Direct` and named it `Setapp`.

[image]

I didn't modify anything regarding the new build config `Setapp`, however, when I build using the `Setapp` build config, I am getting an error.

[image]

It says the library Ensembles cannot be found. It's a library that I installed via Cocoapods.

I can't figure why I am getting this error. Since I am using an exact copy of a build configuration that works (`Direct` in this case), I don't see how `Direct` builds fine but `Setapp` doesn't.

Just as extra information, I am specifying to build using the `Setapp` build configure using Scheme like this:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I need to run `pod install` again.